# disable drop down menu from enabling user to select the filter they are currently viewing

Tags: c#, .net, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown (where autopostback is set to true) with 3 options, such as:

- option A
- option B
- option C

Whenever a user clicks on option A, it does a site search and displays a set of results. Now the since I have already done a search with option A, I would not be able to click/do search with same option,in other words i would be able to do a search on other opitions, option B and option C should be clickable/searchable, but option A should notclickable/should be in read only mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't specific in your post, but if you have a [`DropDownList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist.aspx) that contains [`ListItems`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.aspx), you can simply do this to disable a particular list item:

```
listItem.Enabled = false;
```

I suppose you could call that in your method that searches a particular option.

Comment: Sorry about incomplete post..My requirment here is I need make selected item as Read only value....

Comment: I found solution for my issue Thank you all for your suggestion.

Comment: @user2271011 You should include the solution that fixed your problem for future reference.

Comment: Please Note : The solution is for my issue,First We make the autopostback set to false and second is if autopostback is set to true then make you dropdown selected item as ready only or enable as false..But in my case my search result were wrong